# Django TemplateDoesNotExist : music/index.html

Tags: python, django, web

Ok i have this problem in my code when i run the server and go to the http://127.0.0.1:8000 it's run ok but the problem is ( i have a project called website and an app called music ok when i go to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/music it's tell me this

Exception Type : TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: music/index.html

my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Album
enter code here
enter code here
def index(request):
      all_albums = Album.objects.all()
      context = {
         'all_albums': all_albums
       }
       return render(request, 'music/index.html',context)
```

and this is what my server says 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYTmV.png)

sorry about my English so bad

Comment: Can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: like what do you want?

Comment: What your project looks like. How are your files arranged?

Comment: For a start, *do* you have a "music/index.html" file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add directory

```
 'templates'
```

to your project 
use path

```
 templates/music/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by renaming the folder directory to "templates".